# SML: Does the function foldl take the list predefined, or list could be accumulated during the process?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, fold, smlnj

The following is related to a homework question. Not looking for an answer, looking for a **clarification**

I am supposed to find the n-th Catalan number which is based on a recurrence rel that is not relevant to my question.

My question is:

The function foldl takes a function, an accumulator, and a list

When I apply foldl, it will look something like that
foldl function_name initial_value_for_accumulator list

Our professor says in the question the following:

Implement a function `Catalan:int -> int` which, when given an integer `n`, computes
the n-th Catalan number. For full credit, use the higher order function `foldl` in your solution.

Foldl has to take a list. So, the question is: Am I able to pass a list that is being built up during the recursion? or I have to compute the list and then pass it to foldl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using both recursion and `foldl` is unusual, especially in basic exercises. I believe the professor is telling you to use `foldl` *instead* of recursion.

As you state, this requires you to define a list and pass it to `foldl`. Often, if you need to loop over the numbers from `1` to `n`, you start from the list of such numbers.